# Local URL is not working - Asp .net core - Local iis server

Tags: asp.net, angular, iis, dns, local

I have publish my **asp .net core** into local folder **(D:\le1testing)**. Code published without error.
Also, created site in local IIS server as **le1testing**, and binding the host like below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNCAI.png)

But, when i hit the local domain link, it is not working. it showing the below attached error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqVmO.png)
Anyone help me to fix this iisue.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is the `www.le1testing.com` a public domain name? If not, that means there's no correspond IP address binds to it. Public DNS cannot map the domain to specific server IP.

If you want to access the domain through network, you need to buy a public domain name and map it to server IP.

If you want to access it through LAN or local machine, you can edit hosts file. The file's path is `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`. Add a record like this:`127.0.0.1  www.le1testing.com`. Then you can access it through local machine. Edit other machines' host file like `IIS machine IP  www.le1testing.com` can allow them access site through LAN.